# trying to get a dynamic value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to grab the value of a td for each row that is checked, and add it to itself to figure out total hours. The following is what I have so far. (Note, I've tried variations of .text, .html, and .val.)

```
<tbody>  
   <tr class="">
      <td><input value="32" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Keyword Optimization*</td>  
      <td class="hours" style="">5</td>
      <td>hours</td>  
   </tr>  

</tbody>
```

So in this case, I'm looking to be able to add "5" to the total hours. Here is my jquery:

```
$("input:checked").each(function(){
hrs = parseInt($(this).find(".hours").val) + hrs;
});
alert(hrs + " hours.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find searches child nodes, meaning that the ".hours" nodes will have to be descendants of the inputs (which is wrong).

another thing is that class="hours" is for a td element, which doesn't have .val(), but has .html().

try this:

```
$("input:checked").each(function(){
    hrs = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find(".hours").html()) + hrs;
});
alert(hrs + " hours.")
```

just to explain:

$(this) is the input

.parent() is the td

.parent() is the tr

Comment: you need () after .html because it's a method, not a property

Comment: .html() returns a string, so the + hrs at the end will act as a string concatenation rather than numerical addition. Also, .parent().parent().find() is less efficient than simply doing $(this).siblings('.hours').

Comment: that's why there's parseInt() around it... and you'll need .parent.siblings(), and the complexity is the same, since there's a search in the siblings list.... depth of nodes isn't deep so find() wont be heavy, difference is minor

Comment: ah, right. my mistake. still, .parent().parent().find() is forcing the browser to do more work than necessary, especially in something as rigidly structured as a table.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of hours in the checked row:

```
$("input:checked").each(function(){
    var hrs = $(this).parent().siblings('.hours').text() * 1; //the *1 converts the string '5' to a number
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that find looks in descendents of the node so I think you need:

```
hrs += parseInt($(this.parentNode.parentNode).find(".hours").val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var updateHoursTotal = function () {
  var hours = 0;
  $('#yourtable') // within your table
    .find('input:checked') // get the set of checked boxes
    .closest('tr') // looking up to the enclosing tr
    .find('.hours') // find the .hours cell within
    .each( function(){ // for each
      hours += parseInt( $.trim( $(this).text() ), 10 ); // accumulate total hours
    });
  $('span#counter').html( hours ); // update displayed total somewhere in UI
}
```

You could bind a function like this to the `click` event of each checkbox, for example. If hours can be fractional, a variant solution is left as an exercise.